# Input editText as hex, send as int?

Tags: java, android, hex

I am sending data from my Android app to a bluetooth module using SPP with the following method, which takes an int.

```
      public void writeHex(int i){
        try{
            mmOutStream.write(i);
            }catch (IOException e){   
        }
    }
```

When I use it with an int such as '0xD' it works correctly so there is nothing wrong here. However I am trying to get data from an editText that has been formatted so that it can only accept 0-F as input. From here I thought I would need to add '0x' to the string and then convert to int.

For example my editText has '4E' entered, I then create a new string builder beginning with '0x'. I then append my entered value of 4E to the string and convert to int. However I get an error when trying to convert to int saying it is invalid.

I know this is probably so wrong but I have no better idea of how to do it? Any answers or hints would deb very much appreciated. My code for the the conversion is below:

```
   btnSendHex.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        hexString.append("0x");
        hexString.append(dataInputHex.getText().toString());
        String hexWrite = hexString.toString();
        int hexValue = Integer.parseInt(hexWrite);
        mConnectedThread.writeHex(hexValue);
        }
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: You will likely have to break the string apart and do the conversion on your own.

Comment: Thanks zgc. I understand how to convert the int but it is getting the 0x in front of the value to make it a valid hex value that is causing the problem.

Comment: Right, but try doing it without using toString or the Integer parser. Like get each value in the EditText field and convert it to an int yourself. That way the 0x is of no importance. Or you could just try String myString = "0x" + dataInputHex.getText().toString(); if you really want android to handle the parsing for you. That may work for converting the string like you want.